# Can't send out transactions with Mist wallet

Tags: mist, wallets

All of a sudden on Sunday I started having problems sending ETH out of my Mist wallet. I'm still confirming transactions coming in, and it appears synced just fine.

The transactions never confirm, and I dont get charged for them either. They don't show up on Etherscan either. Here's an [example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcd6d19eb0287b09fb39f68fcb78de285c9dbbb7df8493e4dac045a337e2936a9).

After a bit (like 20 minutes?), the pending transaction dissappears, with the message that `The transaction from Main account (Etherbase) to 0xA3c55cDEF38319E613F7B0593b224448944A9B1d couldn't be successfully executed.`

Seems to happen when choosing any amount, with any fees/gas, and any address I send it to. I saw another post that reccomended to sync my time with NIST, which I did. Didn't seem to help.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: But this one here https://etherscan.io/address/0xA3c55cDEF38319E613F7B0593b224448944A9B1d says you have sent ethers 11 hours ago (as of writing this) too. Is it resolved now?

Comment: No, i was trying to send ether TO that address (which is at an exchange) from my Mist wallet. I was able to send stuff out of the exchange, but still can't send anything out of my wallet.

Comment: [This is the address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a40D96518e8187886cCBD7e86069c3B40E634AF) I am trying to send out of.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the chaindata folder and re-downloading the blockchain fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not mining you can turn on "Light Client Mode" which will sync all Blocks in mere 15minutes compared to hours and hours otherwise...

Launch the Ethereum Wallet application and click Develop -> Sync With Light Client.

Available in version 9.1 onwards.